# rails db:migrate doesn't work after altering the database manually

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I am still new to rails and I have some questions regarding rails migration.

I am using rails 5, windows 8. I generated a model and wrote some code which creates a table with columns. Then I deleted that table from my development db (MySQL) and tried to execute db:migrate again to see if it would create the table and columns written in the migration file. After executing db:migrate, it didn't show any messages in the terminal and it did not create the table and the columns.

Based from my observation, deleting the version of my migration file from schema_migrations and running db:migrate once again, it worked and created the table and columns.

I would like to ask the pros of rails development on why is this happening and what should I do when I start to develop a large database model.

I would also like some suggestions about great resource materials for learning ruby on rails.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `rake db:migrate` is running only migrations for the current env that have not run yet. So if you run db:migrate and then manually delete table form DB, your app does not know that.

[MIgration Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

Comment: Thanks Piotor! So in altering the database itself, I should do it using the migration file? Is it possible to alter the a table using the existing migration file?

Comment: If you wrote migration file and ran rake db:migrate its better to write another migration. You don;t have to, but it is much cleaner. If you want to run all migrations again you can do `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`. For editing last migration you can use rollback, but it all is in guide.